# Error while running Chaincode program

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric

I am writing chaincode program in GO on my MacOS. Following is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim"
    sc "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer"
)

//Init and Invoke
type SmartContract struct {
}

type SomeDocument struct {
    DocumentID   string `json:"docid"`
    CreatorID    string `json:"uid"`
    DocHolder    string `json:"doc_holder"`
    Location     string `json:"location"`
    DocumentType string `json:"doc_type"`
    Content      string `json:"doc_content"`
}

func (s *SmartContract) Init(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) sc.Response {
    return shim.Success(nil)
}

func (s *SmartContract) Invoke(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) sc.Response {

    return shim.Success(nil)
}

func main() {
    first_doc := SomeDocument{"1001", "123456789012", "ABCD EFGH", "New Delhi", "School Form", "I want to enroll in this school"}
    theJson, _ := json.Marshal(first_doc) //returns JSON encoding of first_stamp
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", string(theJson))
    err := shim.Start(new(SmartContract))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error creating new Smart Document: %s", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Success")
    }
}
```

It is showing the following error due to this line, shim.Start(new(SmartContract)):

```
{"docid":"1001","uid":"123456789012","doc_holder":"ABCD EFGH","location":"New Delhi","doc_type":"School Form","doc_content":"I want to enroll in this school"}
    2018-04-10 23:34:41.598 IST [shim] SetupChaincodeLogging -> INFO 001 Chaincode log level not provided; defaulting to: INFO
    2018-04-10 23:34:41.598 IST [shim] SetupChaincodeLogging -> INFO 002 Chaincode (build level: ) starting up ...
    Error creating new Smart Document: error chaincode id not provided%
```

I cannot find any solution.

Is it possible to specify the limit on the length of struct attributes?. For example DocumentID should be length 10.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and where it is failing.

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example

Comment: Please check. I have added now

Answer (score 1):

In you look at [the source](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.1/core/chaincode/shim/chaincode.go#L130) you see it is doing

```
chaincodename := viper.GetString("chaincode.id.name")
if chaincodename == "" {
    return errors.New("error chaincode id not provided")
}
```

I believe you can just do:

```
os.Setenv("chaincode.id.name", "whatever")
```

or

```
chaincode.id.name=whatever go run main.go
```

To get past that.

As far as specifying the length of an attribute, of course you can.  You either use a data structure with a length (e.g. `[10]byte`), or make the field private and verify the length in your setter method.

https://play.golang.org/p/WvG-ZWKhrZ7

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type SomeDocument struct {
    DocumentID   [10]byte `json:"docid"`
    CreatorID    string `json:"uid"`
    DocHolder    string `json:"doc_holder"`
    Location     string `json:"location"`
    DocumentType string `json:"doc_type"`
    Content      string `json:"doc_content"`
}

func (s *SomeDocument) SetDocumentID(id string) {
    copy(s.DocumentID[:], []byte(id))
}

func (s SomeDocument) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    tmp := struct {
    DocumentID   string `json:"docid"`
    CreatorID    string `json:"uid"`
    DocHolder    string `json:"doc_holder"`
    Location     string `json:"location"`
    DocumentType string `json:"doc_type"`
    Content      string `json:"doc_content"`
    }{
    string(s.DocumentID[:]),
    s.CreatorID,
    s.DocHolder,
    s.Location,
    s.DocumentType,
    s.Content,
    }
    return json.Marshal(tmp)
}

func main() {
    s := SomeDocument{}
    s.SetDocumentID("1234567890abcd")
    js, err := json.Marshal(s)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(js))
    // {"docid":"1234567890","uid":"","doc_holder":"","location":"","doc_type":"","doc_content":""}

}
```

Comment: Do I need to set chaincode.id.name in the main? It will still give error as: `cannot refer to unexported name chaincode.id`
I tried os.Setenv, but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you trying to run your chaincode from your IDE or locally, I'd suggest to consult with documentation and particular to see how to [execute chaincode in devmode](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.0/peer-chaincode-devmode.html).

In your case you just missing a few environment variables:

```
export CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGLEVEL=debug 
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1:7052 
export CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc:0 // <--- name and version of your chaincode
```

which needed to execute your chaincode locally.